# Automatic alignment in tabulars

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I am trying to make a table with both left and right alignments. Now I can get the view like this 
[image]

The first problem is with the left alignment - there is a space between left side and tabular with two items.

The second problem is that I have to set width of parboxes manually. Isn't the way to automate that by the width of title? Maybe parboxes is not the best way for wrapping lines in tables?

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{l}

        {\Huge Some title text is written here...} \\
        \Xhline{1.5mm}
        \parbox{11.1cm}{
        \begin{multicols}{2} 
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}     
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                \hline
                 $\boldsymbol{\bigotimes}$  & {\large this is an example} \\
                 \hline
        \end{tabular} \\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
        \end{multicols}
        } \\            
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|cll|}
            \hline
            $\bigcirc$ & 1 & First item & 
                \pbox{7.3cm}{Sed ut perspiciatis unde 
                omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem 
                accusantium doloremque laudantium} \\
            \hline
            $\bigcirc$ & 2 & Second item & Some definition. \\  
            \hline          
        \end{tabular}   
    \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The multiple nested tabulars and parboxes complicate the input, I think you can use a much simpler scheme, something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}

\begin{document}

\noindent


 {\Huge \strut Some title text is written here...\par}
 \hrule height 3pt

\smallskip

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|l|X}
        \cline{1-2}
                 $\boldsymbol{\bigotimes}$  &
       \large this is an example & 
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit\\
        \cline{1-2}
\end{tabularx}
\smallskip

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|llX|}
\hline
            $\bigcirc$ & 1 & First item & 
             Sed ut perspiciatis unde 
                omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem 
                accusantium doloremque laudantium \\
            \hline
            $\bigcirc$ & 2 & Second item & Some definition. \\  
            \hline          
\end{tabularx}   
    \end{document}
```